# 'list' object has no attribute 'lower''list' object has no attribute 'lower' in TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, nlp, vectorization, sentiment-analysis, tfidfvectorizer

i have csv file about some arabic tweet i did token and stemming and clean the text

```
`data = pd.read_csv(r"tweet.csv" ,dtype=str, encoding="utf-8")

    
def preprocessing(text):
\#remove stop words
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('arabic'))
\#takenazation
tokens = word_tokenize(text.lower())
result = \[i for i in tokens if not i  in stop_words\]
\#stemming
als=ArabicLightStemmer();
word_list = \[als.light_stem(w) for w in  result\]
return word_list

data\['text'\]  = data\['text'\].apply(preprocessing)

vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(binary=False,norm='l2',use_idf=True,smooth_idf=True,lowercase=True,min_df=1,
max_df=1.0,max_features=None,ngram_range=(1,1))
vectorizer.fit(data\["text"\])
x=vectorizer.transformv(data\["text"\])
```

i have error in TfidfVectorizer it said that  'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

i want to do vetorization to my text

Answer (score 0):

If the 'text' is in a list format, the lower function does not work for a list.
It works for a string as an element in a list.

So you should input

```
[x.lower() for x in text]
```

as an argument for the function.